# Do variables in a for loop keep track of the previous number?

Tags: c

In this example, let's say `array[1]` is 50 and `array[2]` is 64, does `sum` keep track of the previous number?
When 0 is added to 50 then it loops again, would it be 50 = 0 + 64?

```
//adds up all the numbers in the array and divide by how much is there
float average(int length, int array[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
       int sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    return sum / length;
}
```

Comment: The best way to learn is to attach a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: When the loop iterates it's a fresh run of the code block ,  the variable is conceptually destroyed and recreated

Comment: @drum not in this case, as the debugger won't tell you whether `int sum = sum + array[i];` appears to be working because it's well-defined, or because of chance

Comment: no, your `sum` in the loop is [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `sum` outside the loop. `sum` outside the loop isn't updated.

Comment: @yano so is inside updated? I apologize, i'm a programming noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum` inside the loop is [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `sum` outside that loop.  You need to understand variable scope to understand why this isn't working as you expect.  Your automatic variables (those that live on the stack in most implementations) come alive when you enter a block of code (designated with curly braces `{ ... }`) and die when you leave that block of code.  So when you enter the `average` function, the locals you've declared (`sum`) and the arguments (`length` and `array[]`) come alive.  The `for` loop is another block, and inside that, the second `sum` comes alive.  Since both variables have the same name, the inner-most `sum` is what's operated on, shadowing/blocking the outer `sum`.  Furthermore, since the `for` loop is looping, you enter and leave its block every iteration through the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{  // enter the block here, inner sum comes alive
  int sum = sum + array[i];  
}  // leave the block here, inner sum dies
```

That means that for every loop, you're creating the inner `sum` when you enter, and destroy it when you leave.  As you loop through, you're effectively doing

```
int (inner) sum = (outter) sum + array[0];
int (inner) sum = (outter) sum + array[1];
int (inner) sum = (outter) sum + array[2];
// etc
```

where each `int (inner) sum` is a new variable.

Since outter `sum` is 0, inner `sum` is initialized to the value of `array[i]` for only a brief moment until its destroyed without being used or saved elsewhere when you exit the block.  In reality, the compiler would recognize that this entire `for` loop is useless, and optimize it away.

If you want to sum up the entire array, you need to add the array values to outter `sum`; you don't need a different `sum` variable inside the `for` loop.

```
float average(int length, int array[])
{   // outter sum, length, and array come alive
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
       sum = sum + array[i];  // now, this refers to outter sum, each time thru the loop
    }
    return (float)sum / length;  // the return value is saved somewhere, 
                                 // probably in a register. You need to
                                 // cast at least one operator in the
                                 // expression to do floating point math.
}   // outter sum, length, and array die
```