# How does the sum = sum + array work in this for loop? (I know how for loops work)

Tags: c

Does sum update every time the loop loops"? Like for example, array [0] = 50 and array [1] = 12 when the for loop happens, does the following happen?

//first loop

50 = 0 + 50

//second loop

62 = 50 + 12

OR does the following happen?

//1st loop
0 = 0 + 50

//second loop
50 = 50 + 12

```
float addition(int length, int array[])

{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i];
        
        }
return  sum;
}
```

This isn't homework. I'm just trying to understand the code from my Introduction to Computer Science course on EDX.

Comment: Key thing to understand is that `=` is not checking for equality, but assigning a variable. So it doesn't make sense to ask whether it's `50 = 0 + 50` vs. `0 = 0 + 50`, because both don't make sense. It's instead `sum =  0 + 50`.

Comment: If you want to know what happens to a variable in a loop, print it in the beginning and the end of the loop inside the loop body. You can also print it before and after the loop.

Comment: This example is from an actual course?  And they can't even use the correct return type?

Comment: @MarioIshac So if the initial value of sum is 0, does that mean that 0+50 is assigned to the variable sum?

Comment: @paddy He used casting to fix the return type.

Comment: Yes, 0 + 50 is assigned to `sum` making it 50. Then 50 + 12 is assigned to `sum` making it 62.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you have `int x=5; x=x+10; x=x+4;`, is there anything unclear about what value `x` will have?

Comment: @MarioIshac Okay thanks!

Comment: He used casting to fix the return type? Seriously?

Comment: @paddy It's teaching us about the basics and features of C so I guess he used that as an example. It's on Harvard's Introduction to Computer Science(week2) course on EDx. You can find it in between 1 hour and 11 minutes and 1 hour and 20 minutes.

Comment: @Anique Do you have a link to the video?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do variables in a for loop keep track of the previous number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878615/do-variables-in-a-for-loop-keep-track-of-the-previous-number)

Comment: @paddy https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:HarvardX+CS50+X/block-v1:HarvardX+CS50+X+type@sequential+block@dc45fb6f325d4a7d8d6693d07171e8a5/block-v1:HarvardX+CS50+X+type@vertical+block@c88216de53eb45ec848f4b209222637f

Answer (score 1):

try it and see what happens

```
#include <stdio.h>

float addition(int length, int array[])

{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("about to evaluate %d = %d + %d", sum+array[i], sum, array[i]);
        sum = sum + array[i];
        printf("...pass %d sum %d\n", i+1, sum);
        
        }
return  sum;
}

int main() {
int data[]={50,12};
printf("final result %f\n", addition(2, data));
return 0;
}
```

y u don't say what platform you are using to develop but debugging tools can allow introspection of what is happening inside a running program.  If you want to see what happens in these kind of situations, debuggers are great